# Varios contadores

Tags: python

```
cont=0
def PartidosGanados():
    global cont  
    if [4]>[3]:
       cont+=1
       print(cont)


cant=0        
def PartidosPerdidos():
    global cant
    if[4]<[3]:
      cant+=1
      print(cant)
```

Necesito que cada vez que pase alguno de los sucesos se acumule segun lo que pase, pero cuando se ejecuta lo lee una vez y se sigue sumando pero solo aparece un contador.
gracias

Comment: En la primera función, si no se cumple el `if` es por que se perdió el partido. Es mejor agregar un else

Comment: Cuando lo ejecuto solo lee un contador

Comment: Es obligatorio usar variables globales?? Puede haber empate? ??

Comment: Como asi empate?

Answer (score 1):

Podrías poner un `else` ya que la condición evalúa si se gana, entonces el esle se cumple en caso se pierda.

```py
win=0
loss =0
def PartidosGanados():
    global win
    global loss  
    if [4]>[3]:
       win+=1
       print(win)
    else:
        loss+=1
        print(loss)
```